# Tweepy Cursor.items() not working as expected with api.retweeters

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have some code that looks like this:

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(...)
auth.set_access_token(...)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
for e, i in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.retweeters, '1157819926532501504').items()): # 1157819926532501504 is the id of https://twitter.com/NASA/status/1157819926532501504
    print(e, i)
```

When I run that, I get something like this:

```
0 3249595190
1 1678701169
2 34877330
...
86 625615049
87 1157852235381870592
```

If you look at https://twitter.com/NASA/status/1157819926532501504, you will see that the tweet has 3.2K retweets, whereas only 88 are getting printed out. Why is this? I'm using tweepy.Cursor, so pagination should take care of itself, no? I tried `api.retweeters(id='1157819926532501504', cursor=-1)` to see what was happening to the cursor, and I got a response like this:

```
([3249595190, 1678701169, ..., 625615049, 1157852235381870592], (0, 0))
```

Changing the cursor parameter doesn't change the response, neither does using the `page` parameter.

Am I misunderstanding fundamental? Does twitter not allow one to retrieve all of the retweeters for a tweet? Am I misunderstanding tweepy? I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Just ran into this myself. I think there is a limit to just one page for their free API. I'm still in the midst of searching or where this limit is specifically documented, but I can't get more than one page of retweeters.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit really:100. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-retweets-id

Unfortunately, it didn't always return 100. Sometimes, it returns just 40 ou 50 even if the tweet has 50k retweets.

Solutions:

1) Run a regular search with the exact same text of the original tweet. It's the best chance to retrieve more retweets. Retweets are returned on regular searchs too.

2) If the tweet is "fresh" and "hot" (with a lot of engagement), do several calls. You can get the most recent tweets with that.